# Which crystals can exist permanently (and do not break down) under normal earth like outside conditions?

Tags: chemistry-in-fiction, geochemistry

Hi I am looking for crystals I can use in the world of my novel but I have no idea what types to use or what there are.

So my question is what kind of crystals fit these criteria:

- They must be able to exist “permanently” without breaking down in normal earth conditions/atmosphere.
- They must be able to grow quite large. (I’m thinking about large hexagonal crystal columns)

I would be very happy if you could list any crystals you know that fist the criteria. With the name I should be able to research further myself and narrow it down.
Thanks in advance.

-

***P.s. some of you might have some feeling of déjà vu reading my question as I asked a similar question before but that one was marked as to brought so I am asking it again but trimmed down.***
link: [How do i create a significantly correct world with large crystal formations in my novel?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64763/)

P.p.s. if this question is to brought as well please leave a comment explaining how I can make it better because I otherwise really have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Instead of re-asking a question, you might want to edit the original and get it reopened. If the questions are too similar, they might get closed as duplicates.

Comment: There are **thousands** of minerals out there. A good many of them would exist permanently if exposed to elements; they've been through it before. Most of those are crystalline and would grow into large crystals, given the right conditions (which are rarely there, but anyway).

Comment: Have a look for 'Cave of the Crystals' in the Naica Mine in Mexico. The crystals there should suffice.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks but they break down (although slowly) when exposed to air so they are not an option. Honestly it was the first thing i thought off when i started thinking about the idea but since they need to be "permanent" so they are not an option.

Comment: I would go with quartz, you can even make it basically any color you like. But I would ask that question in a geology forum.

Comment: @ TheRWS96 Its possible to grow very large Alum crystals quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz (silicon dioxide) sounds like a good bet. It is inert, safe to be around, and insoluble in water. Some examples of naturally occurring quartz crystals are really huge - visit the National Museum of Natural History if you are near DC - or any other natural history museum near you. There you will likely see many other naturally occurring minerals of defined chemical composition that form large crystals. Or go online and look for pictures.

Answer (score 1):

for a permanently persisting cristal, I would think of diamond.

For an hexagonal structure, I would think of basaltic organ (bu this is not a cristal)